# Symlink lost within Docker image

Tags: sqlite, docker, rust, symlink

I am defining a Dockerfile where I install `sqlite3` in a `ubuntu` based image, something very similar (I also install grpc and rust as well as all the necessary dependencies) to:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev&& \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove
```

I use this image to built my Rust project within it. The issue that I am facing is that `cargo build` fails on my GitLab CI due to a linking issue:

```
Compiling migrations_macros v1.4.0
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
...
= note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
```

I found out that this is due to this symlink not being present on the Docker image that is running on CI:

```
libsqlite3.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

while the file `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` exists. So if I create the symlink during the CI jobs I can have a working workaround. The weird thing is that if I pull the same exact image from my registry on my pc and run the container I can build without any issue and any change because the symlink is actually there.

What could be the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of thinking the following ideas come to my mind which could help.

- Docker history

Docker command has a build in feature to view the history of a built image. You have the option to identify the problematic command in the DockerFile.

```
docker history <image id or name>
```

For more visual filtering i do recommend [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) tool but others are also available on google.

- Correct docker version

Since in this scenario the two docker instances are different the question is trivial. Are they on the same version of docker daemon and docker file system driver?